# No. of non-negative Integral Solutions through two methods

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The number of non-negative integral solutions of
$$x_1~ + ~x_2~ + ~x_3~ + ~...~ + ~x_r~ = ~n$$
can be written as $$^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$$

This can be found in two ways (*as far as I know*) -

1. Arrange $r-1$ pluses($+$) & $n$ ones($1$) in a row -> $^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$

For example: $x + y + z = 4$, then $\frac{1}{} \frac{+}{}\frac{1}{}\frac{1}{} \frac{+}{} \frac{1}{}$ is one of the arrangements and we find the total no. of such arrangements

2. Finding the coefficient of $x^n$ in
   $$(x^0 + x^1 + ... + x^n)^r$$

I know that we get the same value [which is $^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$] from the second method too but **why do we find the coefficient of $x^n$ in this series ? What is the understanding behind using the second method ?**

I could have said "finding no. of ... is same as finding the coefficient of $n$ in $(1+x)^{n+r-1}$ " but it is not taught like so, which means there is some importance in using that series. So I want to know that importance of the series in finding the no. of arrangements.

Comment: It’s simpler if you don’t end the terms at $x^n.$ Just do an infinite sum.

Comment: $$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\tag 1$$ is more complicated than $$1+x+x^2+\cdots =\frac{1}{1-x}\tag2$$(2) is simpler than (1).

Comment: what you did in (2) is only when |x|<1 ..

Comment: It’s not clear what your question is about. Are you wondering why the power coefficient counts the combinatorics question, or why the value from the power series coefficient also ends up $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$

Comment: 1st part of what you wrote, "why the power coefficients counts the combinatorics question". In my question I have specified that I know how we get $^{n+r-1}C_(r-1)$ from 2nd method

Comment: That’s true about $|x|<1,$ but when talking about power series abstractly like this, we don’t need convergence for specific real values of $x.$ These are “abstract power series,” and $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)=1$ where $x$ is considered an “indeterminate.”

Comment: https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/AC.pdf is on "Analytic Combinatorics" which is all about using formal power series coefficients to solve counting problems.   With formal power series, we don't care about convergence, yeah

Comment: @Alan it would be best if you could write an answer, frankly the pdf won't help till I read it with enough time on hand

Comment: @Goarkz I would if I remembered, I took a course on that book 5 years ago.  I was just sharing the resource for future study

Comment: Could you guide me about which topics should read, in specific, for this particular question?